# Log-normal density function using rlnorm() in R

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, density-function, random-generation, lognormal-distribution

I tried to draw a log-normal density function by generating random numbers in R. However, the function is not working how I think it should. I draw two similar distribution using two different sample size.

```
plot(density(rlnorm(1000000,meanlog = -1.43, sdlog = 0.7)))

plot(density(rlnorm(100000000,meanlog = -1.43, sdlog = 0.7)))
```

For some reason, I got two very different distributions.
[image]

[image]

Am I getting something wrong? I thought that these two density function should be nearly similar.

Edit:

I draw the density function also in excel. I think this should be the correct distribution. Is there some error in R-function?

[image]

Comment: what is the default number of samples?  How does that compare to your domain width?

Comment: The area under the first density is around 1.0 while the area under the second is around 3.0.  A fix (and NOT an explanation) is to use a larger number of points to estimate the density:  `plot(density(rlnorm(100000000,meanlog = -1.43, sdlog = 0.7), n=2^12))`.

Comment: I was a bit sloppy in my terminology:  By "use a larger number of points to estimate the density" I didn't mean the number of random sample points but rather the number of points used to created the display.  The default number of display points for `density` is 512 but that just isn't enough in this case.  I think the problem is because `density` calls the function `fft` with too few sample points for this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with `density()` and not with `rlnorm()`: controlling the support of the estimated density produces a complete agreement for different sample sizes:

```
plot(density(rlnorm(1e7),from=0,to=10),col="steelblue",lty=1)
lines(density(rlnorm(1e6),from=0,to=10),col="steelblue2",lty=2)
lines(density(rlnorm(1e5),from=0,to=10),col="steelblue3",lty=3)
curve(dlnorm,add=TRUE,col="sienna3",lty=4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your density functions are the same. You can sort of eyeball it from the graph. Because the lognormal distribution is (somewhat) heavy tailed, the more random numbers you generate, the higher the chance of generating a very big number.

The density function takes all the numbers it's given and plots the density across all of them, so if you have a number way out at 100, it's going to squish everything else into the corner. Try generating the random numbers again - you'll likely have a graph that looks a little different.